# Pass data between view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

I have this code in my appdelegate but only when I add the line loginViewController.fnameText = @"Text"; My application crashes while if I remove it all works very well, however for me it is very important to pass this line, you have a solution?
Thank you for your reply

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone_47" bundle:nil];
DEMOSearchVideosViewController *loginViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"searchViewController"];
loginViewController.fnameText = @"Text"; // Not wroking -- crash
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
[self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:loginViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Comment: Try to log your loginViewController to check whether it's `null`.

Comment: @KyleEmmanuel, passing a message to nil doesn't cause a crash. It's a no-op

Comment: @victor, could you also post the crash log please

Comment: My problem is resolved guys thanks

Comment: @victorbill that's good to hear. kudos.

Answer (score 0):

Try to print the "loginViewController" object. It should not be non-null. Also, "fnameText" should be declared as a writable property in "DEMOSearchVideosViewController" class. Because you are trying to set a property on the instance.